# Example matplotlib.org does not work in Canopy

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, canopy

I am trying to make an animation with matplotlib in python (2.7) with 3 subplots. To see how this works I tried to understand the example on matplolib.org:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/subplots.html

However when I run this program I only see one of the three plots displayed. Sometimes its the upper right one, sometimes the lower right one.

In my own code I also only see one of the three displayed. Does anyone know if this is a problem with Enthought Canopy and how to fix this?.

Comment: My guess is that the blitting is behaving badly....

Answer (score 1):

Solved, if you set in canopy: preferences > python > PyLab backend: interactive (wx), for some reason it works.

Comment: Indeed, it is odd. I am not able to reproduce your problem on Windows, Mac, or Linux. All the matplotlib examples should work with the Qt backend (which is the Canopy default.) Was yours a fresh installation of Canopy, or perhaps an old one with old libraries? Which OS, and which version of Canopy?

Comment: I am using Mac OS X 10.9.5 and Canopy Version: 1.4.1 (64 bit). A friend of mine had exactly the same problem on his MacBook after he installed Canopy.